# How to calculate the maximal domain and hence range in this question?

Tags: calculus, polynomials, function-and-relation-composition

> Question:
>
> The function $f : R → R, f (x)$ is a polynomial function of degree 4.
> Part of the graph of $f$ is shown below. The graph of $f$ touches the
> x-axis at the origin.
>
> [image]

part a) wants me to find the rule of $f$, which I did:

$f(x) = -4x^2\left(x^2-1\right)$

It then asks for

Let $g$ be a function with the same rule as $f$.

Let  $h : D → R, h (x) =$ $ln\left(g\left(x\right)\right)-ln\left(x^3+x^2\right)$, where $D $is the maximal domain of $h$.

b) State $D$

So first what does it mean by "maximal domain?" Does it mean that I have to find the domain in which the Maximum occurs?

c) State the range of $h$

So I guess I have to simplify  $ln(-4x^2\left(x^2-1\right))-ln\left(x^3+x^2\right)$, and so I did.

$h(x) = ln\left(-4\left(x-1\right)\right)$

I keep trying by have no success. What is the general approach when solving for domain /range? What are the things that I should keep in mind?

Comment: I would guess they mean the largest set $D$ over which $h$ is define. A quick peak looks like its $(0,1)$. Outside of that I think one of the logs will be undefined.

Comment: @Wintermute Looks like your are correct, the answer is $(−1,0) ∪ (0,1)$. What do you mean by  largest set$ D$ over which $h$ is define.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $\quad y = -4x^2(x^2-1)\implies x\in\mathbb{R}$

Solving for $x$, we get
$$x = \pm\frac{\sqrt{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - y}}}{\sqrt{2}}\implies -\infty \le y\le1$$
Any $y>1$ results in complex numbers. This form also suggests that $-\infty \le x \le \infty$ because the square root of [a number approaching] infinity is $\pm$ infinity.